# Is it poor design to have many multiprocessing barriers within a program?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a program where I need to be able to synchronize multiple processes using a multiprocessing.Barrier. Within those processes, I may or may not have (depending on the current stage of execution) multiple threads, which also need to be considered for this synchronization.

My solution is to assign each execution stage a barrier upfront, which has the correct parties count initialized. E.g. 8 parties for 4 processes with 2 threads each, 4 parties for 4 processes with single threads.

```
barrier_stage1 = multiprocessing.Barrier(parties=4)
barrier_stage2 = multiprocessing.Barrier(parties=8)
barrier_stage3 = multiprocessing.Barrier(parties=4)
... # these are dynamically created during initialization
```

This means that I may have up to a hundred multiprocessing.Barrier instances created upfront, each of which will only be used once during runtime.

Is this poor design?